# stack execution protection and randomization on ubuntu

Tags: c, security, stack-overflow, buffer-overflow

As part of a course assignment i need to write an exploit code to cause a buffer overflow and execute code that is present on stack.

I have turned off the stack randomiztion by the following command:
sysctl -w kernel.randomize_va_space=0
However, i am unable to find a way to turn off the stack execution protection. I am not sure whether there is some stack exec protection in ubuntu or not... so my first question is whether there is something like red hat's exec-shield in ubuntu 8.10 and if there is, how can we turn it off.

I have been trying to cause a buffer overflow and execute instruction from stack, but whenever i try to do so, it gives me a seg fault.

i ve got ubuntu 8.10 64 bit, HOWEVER, the program im debugging is compiled on an i386 machine with stack protection turned off.

Comment: Would [this link](http://pwet.fr/man/linux/administration_systeme/execstack) help?

Comment: *lol* the war against crackers is stopping our white-hats to learn the trade. Maybe the criminals will go away when we don't know how they do it? ;)

Answer (score 5):

You probably want to compile with the `-z execstack` flag in your GCC compilation, along with `-fno-stack-protector` (to disable GCC's SSP/Propolice stack protection), i.e:

```
gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -o vuln vuln.c
```

Everything should probably turn out jake after this.  Note that `sysctl -w kernel.randomize_va_space=0` is just address space randomization, and not stack protection, per-se; which may be brute forced against using a variety of techniques.

Answer (score 0):

These programs can often be exploited without executable stacks.  If the victim is compiled without executable stack, consider return-oriented programming as an exploit technique.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return-oriented_programming